# Show table with results grouped 3 by 3

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to show results that I get from a SQL table, it is this:

[image]

what I want to do is show results 3 by 3, like this:

[image]

I mean a table for every 3 results that the "assigned_bank" field matches, and if there are 4 results with the same number in "assigned_bank", I also show it in that same table, that is; one table for each different "assigned_bank" id.
I've been trying most of the day and the closest thing I've come to is this:

[image]

This is my last code:

```html
<?php
$tables = sizeof($search) / 3;
for ($i = 0; $i < $tables; $i++) {

?>
    <table class="table customers">
        <thead class="thead-blue">
            <tr>
                <th scope="col-xs-2">Name</th>
                <th scope="col-xs-2">Lastname</th>
                <th scope="col-xs-2">Bank ID</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        
        <?php
        foreach ($search as $item){
            echo '<tr align="left">';
            echo '<td class="col-xs-2">' . $item["p_name"] . '</td>' . "\r\n";
        echo '<td class="col-xs-2">' . $item["p_lastname"] . '</td>' . "\r\n";
        echo '<td class="col-xs-2">' . $item["assigned_bank"] . '</td>' . "\r\n";
        echo '</tr>';
        }
        ?>
           
        </tbody>
    </table>
   
    <?php
        echo "\r\n";
    
}
?>
```

Thank you very much for any possible help or comments and thank you for taking the time to respond.

Comment: The first part is fine but then why in the second part the same repeated twice for 1 and 10 each ? What is the logic there?

Comment: Whole question is misleading 3x3 is a distraction you seem to want everything ordered by bank with headers between banks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<?php
$result = array();

foreach ($search as $key => $item) {
   $result[$item['assigned_bank']][$key] = $item;
}

foreach($result as $key=>$search_items){
    echo '<table class="table customers" border="2" >
                <thead class="thead-blue">
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col-xs-2">Name</th>
                        <th scope="col-xs-2">Lastname</th>
                        <th scope="col-xs-2">Bank ID</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>';
                foreach($search_items as $skey=>$item){
                    echo '<tr align="left">';
                    echo '<td class="col-xs-2">' . $item["p_name"] . '</td>' . "\r\n";
                    echo '<td class="col-xs-2">' . $item["p_lastname"] . '</td>' . "\r\n";
                    echo '<td class="col-xs-2">' . $item["assigned_bank"] . '</td>' . "\r\n";
                    echo '</tr>';
                }
                
                echo '</tbody>
                </table>';
}
<?>
```

[image: Grouped By assigned_bank]

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to help me :) <3

Answer (score 1):

You can use order by on assigned_bank column with ascending order:

```
SELECT p_name, p_lastname, assigned_bank FROM your_table order by  
assigned_bank asc
```